# iPad Retina Launch Image -- Only top half of the image is displayed

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I've added launch images for the iPad retina display. I use the required sizes.

When the app is run on the simulator, the launch images look fine. When run on actual devices (tested 2 devices, both New iPad (3rd generation)), only the top half of the image shows up, the bottom half of the screen is black.

Once the launch image is dismissed, everything is displayed properly.

If I assign the smaller (non-Retina) launch images, they display properly (though the image is not crisp, obviously).

Any thoughts?

Note: these are 2.4 MB png files.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is your retina launch image corrupted? on simulator the non-retina version is used. you may want to regenerate your retina graphics just to make sure.

Comment: @iBlue The image was corrupted. Thank you! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @iBlue just a reminder to come back and repost your comment as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks again!

Comment: Lol i think it's too short for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the image files were corrupted. Oddly, they opened fine in Preview and Safari, but not in the app for some reason. Anyway, I recreated the images, and all was well.

Answer (score 2):

You need image assets for both retina and non-retina, landscape and portrait.  Use this naming convention:

Default-Landscape~ipad.png, Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png, Default-Portrait~ipad.png, Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png

the @2x images are at retina resolution

Comment: I have all 4 of these images, named according to the convention you mentioned.